# how I can get the next data in mysql

Tags: mysql

really do not know if you can, but i I need the DATE VENC to be equal to '2013-02-02'.
the values of the column date_pay:

```
1-2013-01-01
2-2013-02-02
3-0000-00-00
4-0000-00-00
```

this is my query:

```
   SELECT s.id,
     s.name,
     s.nro_s,
     ts.cat,
     SUM( ts.pryce ) AS deuda, 
     SUM( ts.pryce ) DIV ts.pryce AS c_p,
    date_venc = (select max(date_pay) from c  ) // the date in question
    FROM s
    INNER JOIN c
    INNER JOIN ts
    WHERE s.id =  '123'
    AND c.id =  '123'
    AND c.date_pay =  '0000-00-00'
    AND s.ts = ts.id_ts
```

Sorry for my english, is very basic.
Greetings.

Comment: is the syntax correct ?

Comment: this is the original query, without the date: SELECT s.id,
     s.name,
     s.nro_s,
     ts.cat,
     SUM( ts.pryce ) AS deuda, 
     SUM( ts.pryce ) DIV ts.pryce AS c_p,
     FROM s
    INNER JOIN c
    INNER JOIN ts
    WHERE s.id =  '123'
    AND c.id =  '123'
    AND c.date_pay =  '0000-00-00'
    AND s.ts = ts.id_ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming date_venc is DATE a possible solution

```
 select * 
    from s 
    where s.date_venc=
    (select max(cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_pay,'-',-3)as DATE))from c);

also check out sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64197/1
```

and your query should probably be modified to,

```
SELECT s.id,
     s.name,
     s.nro_s,
     ts.cat,
     SUM( ts.pryce ) AS deuda, 
     SUM( ts.pryce ) DIV ts.pryce AS c_p,
    date_venc
    FROM s
    INNER JOIN c
    INNER JOIN ts
    WHERE s.id =  '123'
    AND c.id =  '123'
    AND c.date_pay =  '0000-00-00'
    AND s.ts = ts.id_ts
    AND date_venc = (select max(cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_pay,'-',-3)as DATE)) from c  ) // the date in question
```